# Is there any potential performance issue if I make many storeviews in Magento

Tags: performance, magento

I run an MLM business (www.mysitename.com) reaching out to a 1000 amateur business owners. My site is based on Magento.

I intend to give each one of them a customized store views (eg partnername.mysitename.com) that they can then promote. The store views are essentially a replica of my original store view with minor UI tweaks. All store views are mapped to the same root category (again same as my main store view).

Does anyone see any downside to this? My main concern is potential performance issues if i create a 1000 such store views. I am hoping that if magentogo can run thousands of sites with different catalogs, then inherently magento is capable delivering this for me (especially since in my case  the catalog is the same).

But what i dont want to avoid is getting all this done and launched, only to realize that the 1st 20 sites worked great but when the number reached hundreds the performance got completely eroded.

Any opinion /suggestions on best practices would be highly appreciated.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the non-opinion part of the question:  The number of store views does not inherently affect performance.  The rate of pages being served will be the limiting factor.

For serving a great number of pages you can run a server farm which spreads the load.  Databases will be replicated in a master-slave configuration where all changes to the data are submitted to the master first.  Such is the complexity of Magento that there is new data being written to the database on almost every page view.  The speed with which these writes can occur on the master database will inevitably be the bottleneck.  Your overall strategy must be to reduce the number of writes, or page impressions, per visitor.

Start by researching Magento on multiple servers and try to find how many pages/sec others have managed to achieve.  Then estimate how many pages/sec each of your businesses will generate and you can then calculate the maximum store views supported.